# Changing foreach into lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8

I wanted to change foreach to lambda expression. Did I make it correct?

```
Map<String, String> countriesToChooseAsMainCountry = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Foreach:

```
for (Country country : project.getCountries()) {
   countriesToChooseAsMainCountry.put(Long.toString(country.getId()), country.getName());
}
```

Lambda:

```
project.getCountries()
       .forEach(country -> countriesToChooseAsMainCountry.put(Long.toString(country.getId()), country.getName()));
```

If I made it correct, can I somehow improve readability of this? Thanks.

Comment: Your two "Foreach" vs "Lambda" examples are exactly identical. You're just populating a map with stuff.

Comment: Can you edit the question, so that it makes sense? Like @Mena said, the Foreach and the Lambda code is the same.

Comment: @Mena Sry, my bad, copied the same thing, corrected it.

Comment: Edit: yes, your idioms are equivalent.

Comment: @Mena which form should i choose?

Comment: @cerbin you're probably safer with the imperative pre-lambda idiom, but I suspect you could use the lambda as well, or nullpointer's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) as:

```
project.getCountries()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(country -> Long.toString(country.getId()), // key
                                 Country::getName, //value 
                                 (a, b) -> b, // function to determine the value in case of same country ids (which is essentially overriding the value) 
                                 LinkedHashMap::new));
```

It prevents you from the nondeterministic behavior of the [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) which though with your current implementation(requirements) seems fine.

Comment: That's a nice alternative but explains little and doesn't directly answer the OP's question.

Comment: Hi @nullpointer. Upvoted, but I think you should at least explain why in `(a, b) -> b` you are returning `b` instead of `a`. At least a sentence about the merge function.